# Swift Package Manager failing after updating to Xcode 14

Tags: ios, xcode, swiftui, swift-package-manager

I have a function called `.readSize` that, in SwiftUI, allows a child View to report its size to its parent View. The function is included in an extension to the `View` struct. Before upgrading to Xcode 14 this package was working. Now, at Xcode 14.0.1, it does not work. Xcode simply tells me that `Text` has no member `.readSize`. When I check, the Project Navigator is showing the package and I can open the module containing `.readSize`.

(The logic for reporting child size is taken from the [Five Stars](https://www.fivestars.blog/articles/swiftui-share-layout-information/) blog).

When I click on the project in the Project Navigator, click on the Project field and click the "Package Dependencies" tab then the "packages" section is empty. If I tap on the "+" symbol then Xcode presents a popover with an "Add Local" button. Clicking that will allow me to find the package and add it. That process, however, merely duplicates the package in the Project Navigator. In the Package Dependencies tab the "packages" section is still empty.

I have tried some of the standard cleanup approaches, such as removing the package, performing a clean, restarting Xcode, and then re-introducing the package with File -> Add Packages. I get the same error.

At a guess, it may be that my package is no longer defined property. The manifest reads as follows:

```
// swift-tools-version:5.5
// The swift-tools-version declares the minimum version of Swift required to build this package.

import PackageDescription

let package = Package(
    name: "ViewExtensions",
    platforms: [.iOS("13.0")],
    products: [
        // Products define the executables and libraries a package produces, and make them visible to other packages.
        .library(
            name: "ViewExtensions",
            targets: ["ViewExtensions"]),
    ],
    dependencies: [
        // Dependencies declare other packages that this package depends on.
        // .package(url: /* package url */, from: "1.0.0"),
    ],
    targets: [
        // Targets are the basic building blocks of a package. A target can define a module or a test suite.
        // Targets can depend on other targets in this package, and on products in packages this package depends on.
        .target(
            name: "ViewExtensions",
            dependencies: []),
        .testTarget(
            name: "ViewExtensionsTests",
            dependencies: ["ViewExtensions"]),
    ]
)
```

I'm at a standstill. Is there some way to debug why Xcode will not allow me to add my package under Package Dependencies?